# Create mlflow experiment: Run with UUID is already active

Tags: python, mlflow

I'm trying to create a new experiment on mlflow but I have this problem:

```
Exception: Run with UUID l142ae5a7cf04a40902ae9ed7326093c is already active.
```

This is my code:

```py
import mlflow
import mlflow.sklearn
import sys

mlflow.set_experiment("New experiment 2")

mlflow.set_tracking_uri('http://mlflow:5000')
st= mlflow.start_run(run_name='Test2')
id = st.info.run_id
mlflow.log_metric("score", score)
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(model, "wineModel")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `mlflow.end_run()` to repair the active run. Then you can create new ones.

---

Note: the problematic run should have `Lifecycle Stage: active` (rather than deleted) displayed in MLflow web UI, so if you deleted it when trying to solve the problem, it needs to be first restored / undeleted (it can be found in the "trash" using MLFlow web UI thus: Filter > State > Deleted).